# Weird outcomes using V4L2, python, on raspberry pi 3

Tags: python, opencv, v4l2

Weird coding outcome which isn't making much sense. I am trying to capture from a raspberry pi camera using the V4L2 driver as I need to use cv2 for image processing. I am using python to write the code.

The weirdness revolves around capturing images using cv2. when I type in the following commands

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
grab,frame = camera.read()
pyplot.imshow(frame)
```

I am able to grab a frame and display it using matplotlib. When I grab a second frame

```
grab,frame2 = camera.read()
pyplot.imshow(frame2)
```

The code will grab a second frame and display it perfectly fine.

However when I try to use an existing variable like `frame` or `frame2` the camera will not grab a new frame and just print the prior frame.

I tried to clear the variable by typing

```
frame = []
grab,frame = camera.read()
pyplot.imshow(frame)
```

but this didn't fix the issue, still printing the prior frame.

Comment: Try checking the error status from the `camera.read()`

Comment: check error status? the function `camera.read()` doesn't produce an error. It generates an HxWx3 matrix with dtype = uint8.

Comment: `grab` is set True or False depending whether the read was successful. I was suggesting you check that.

Comment: I see. The grab variable is True whenever I use `camera.read()`. As a test, I installed *cheese* to see if I was able to acquire video through the V4L2 driver. I was able to see a video perfectly fine. This has to be a problem with openCV 3.4.1

Comment: How do you know it is still printing the first frame exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are *"suffering from buffering"*!

When **OpenCV** reads a frame, it tends to gather a few, I think it is 5 frames or so, or there may be some algorithm that determines available memory or something similar.

Anyway, the answer is to read a few more frames to clear the buffer and then it will acquire some fresh frames.

Comment: When I used Cheese to grab a video from the pi camera using V4L2, I recieved the following **(cheese:3575): cheese-WARNING **: A lot of buffers are being dropped.: gstbasesink.c(2834): gst_base_sink_is_too_late (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstViewfinderBin:vf-bin/ClutterGstVideoSink:cluttergstvideosink0:
There may be a timestamping problem, or this computer is too slow.** I am using a raspberry pi 3 which only has 1gb of ram.

Comment: I did what you suggested and it did fix the issue. It is a buffering issue. after grabbing 5 additional frames, I was able to grab a "new" frame. This though makes my original question more confusing. I am unable to visualize the frames using `cv2.imshow` but it appears nothing is not working. very confusing